# ng-packagr packaged lib: only minified component names work

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

I made a angular (7.2) library, bundled with ng-packagr, published on npm. Now I want to use it in another project. I can import the module, but not the containing components:

The module in my library project which I bundle looks like

```
import { ConfirmDialogComponent } from './dialogs/confirm/confirm-dialog.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  entryComponents: [
    ConfirmDialogComponent
  ],
  declarations: [
    ConfirmDialogComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    ConfirmDialogComponent
  ]
})
export class MyComponents { }
```

In target project I install the published bundle with npm and import the module in `app.modules.ts

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MyComponents } from 'my-components';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MyComponents
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

No error so far, but when I use it in `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfirmDialogComponent } from 'my-components';
```

the statement leads to the compilation error of

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(2,10): error TS2305: Module '"../../node_modules/my-components/my-components"' has no exported member 'MessageDialogComponent'.
```

If I look at `node_modules/my-components/my-components.d.ts`

```
/**
 * Generated bundle index. Do not edit.
 */
export * from './my-components.module';
export { ConfirmDialogComponent as ɵa } from './dialogs/confirm/confirm-dialog.component';
```

and this `app.component.ts` to

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ɵa } from 'my-components';
```

it works!

So why does the minified (?) alias work but not the real name of the component?

--

edit: If I remove as ɵa from declaration file I can Use the comonent's real name as expected. Whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use barrel file as entry file for ng-packagr `public_api.ts` instead of the (angular) module file.

```
export * from './my-components.module'; // don't forget to export the module itself
export * from './dialogs/confirm/confirm-dialog.component';
```